# Table Layout inside Listview - Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scroll

I am creating a table in which there will be several rows. 
So i have used ListView (to make it scrollable) and then in that i create a table layout dynamically. and then i add rows dynamically.

But, my application crashes giving the error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView.

Any solutions ?

Comment: return the table layout inside the adapters getView

Comment: Solved... Using ScrollView... But will try out your method also...

Comment: can you guide me through this , i too want similar kind of functnalty